# Is it physically possible to dodge arrows?

Tags: humans, physics

So first things first: I was not sure where to put this question. It isn't specifically about worldbuilding (though I'm using it that way). It's more related to the capabilities of the human body, but I wasn't sure if it should go on Health SE, Physical Fitness SE, or somewhere else, so I decided to put it here based on what I'm using it for. If it needs to be moved, please feel free to flag it for that.

My question is simple: is it physically possible for a human to dodge an arrow? I realize this probably depends on a lot of factors, like the arrow's speed, the human's condition and weight, the distance involved, and more that I'm probably not thinking of. Speaking in *very* general terms, assume that the arrow is a typical Native American arrow, fired at medium to long range. Also assume that the human dodging said arrow is relatively unencumbered and in prime physical condition, and has extensive agility training.

Please let me know if you require more details. This is a general discussion, and not a specific scene in a book or anything, so generalizations are welcome.

Comment: Thomas.  Please define, with numbers, your range,  and include the draw weight on the bow, that will give an indication of the power behind the arrow.

Comment: Are you talking a flat trajectory or an arc?

Comment: Physically possible for a human to dodge an arrow? Yes, for sure. Easily? Probably not. Would it most likely be a combination of luck and bad aim? Yup.

Comment: When I searched you-tube for dodging arrows, it found 5500+ videos, many with the words like "Horribly Wrong" in their title.  Unfortunately, most involve animals and line-dancing, so humanity is at least a little smarter than I assumed.  Didn't find any proof that it can be done, but had a lot of fun looking!  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Considering that people [catch arrows - 10 catches in 2 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmvHGmKITp4), it is clearly possible to dodge arrows. Watch the video and you can see that dodging is definitely possible.

Paying sufficient attention under combat conditions, lighting, and possible multiple archers means that this is clearly not the safest activity, but it is definitely possible. I would also said that catching an arrow qualifies as successfully dodging an arrow too.

---

The video states the arrows are going 110 km/hour, this is on the slow side for initial velocity from a longbow, but they don't say whether 110 kph is initial, average, or final velocity. However, 13 meters is not very far for the flight distance in combat either.  Given the mass, flight time, and aerodynamics of arrow, I don't expect a large difference between initial and final speed -- perhaps 5 kph difference in total. If the initial speed was a little higher (and presumably more typical) arrow catching and dodging would still appear to be possible given some additional flight distance. The limiting factor for dodging may well be how good the illumination is as well as wind conditions. Full daylight with a high contrast sky background would be essential for best results. Having better than 20/20 vision would also be a big plus. The advantage is definitely tilted in favor of the attacker, esp. given that you have to dodge every time, but a single hit can incapacitate or kill.

110 kph is about 100 ft/sec. Fastest arrow speed from a wooden bow is about 180 fps. American Indians often used flat-bows, and their drawstrings were not as good as those found in modern wooden bows, so 180 fps (197.5 kph) seems like a safe, or even generous speed for American Indian arrows.

As a weapon, arrow momentum is important in terms of combat damage. Does anyone know if American Indians used a heavier but slower arrow in combat?

Comment: Thanks Gary, that's what I was looking for. Incidentally, I remember the mythbusters tested catching arrows and found it couldn't be done... I guess they were wrong.

Comment: Mythbusters tested it and found it impossible and they also found a guy who could catch them.  The key factor:  Arrow catching is done with arrows traveling far below combat speed.  Also look at their attempt to dodge blaster bolts--again, a failure.

Comment: IIRC the mythbusters proved that no amount of skill can enable it with meaningful reliability unless the circumstances support it, basically that you always need both skill **and** suitable circumstances. The myth was along the lines that skill is an effective defense against arrows. Which is pretty much what the answer seems to say. It is all about the flight time observed by the one trying to dodge. And the number of arrows...

Comment: I watched someone who had a partner fire arrows at him from across the other end of a basketball court.  He began by deflecting arrows with a stick.   Then he deflected them with his arm.   Then he caught a couple.  The arrow and fletching were over-sized, so I believe the arrow was slower than what a standard arrow would be.  Also, his partner very carefully aimed so that the arrow was always exactly where he was expecting it.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson -- over-sized arrayhead and fletching would slow the arrow a little, but they definitely make the arrow easier to see.

Answer (score 4):

In mythbusters show season 6 there is an episode were the test various ninja myths. One such myth was the ability to catch an arrow in battle. While they provided it impossible to catch an arrow in battle, they provided it could be done in controlled circumstance. The controlled circumstance need for it to be possible include that the archer must be far enough a way and only shoot one shot every so minute.

Dodging the an arrow is probably some what easier to dodge a arrow, but like catching an arrow it would be a very usefully skill in battle, you might be able to dodge one or two shots, but if they kept shooting at you or if some of there archer friends came to help then your dead. A skill like that is but delay your death but it alone wouldn't save your life.